# Leaflet 1.0 fitBounds not working as expected with ajax loading

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet

I'm having trouble with my leafletJS.

I have multiple geoJson files (lets say seven), which are loaded by ajax and I want to fitBounds after all files are loaded.

I have something like this:

```
function BoundsObject() {
   this.boundsArray = [];
}

function addGeoJsonToMap(map, geojson, boundsObject) {
 var newLayer = L.geoJson(geojson);
 map.addLayer(newLayer);
 var current_bounds = newLayer.getBounds();
    var southwest = current_bounds.getSouthWest();
    var northeast = current_bounds.getNorthEast();
    boundsObject.boundsArray.push([[southwest.lat, southwest.lng], [northeast.lat, northeast.lng]]);
}
function downloadFile(fileurl, map, boundsObject) {
 return $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        dataType: "json"}).done(function(geojson) {
        if (geojson)  {
            addgeojsontomap(map, geojson, boundsObject);
        }
    });
}
```

This is how my map looks like:

```
<div id="someid" class="my-leaflet-map" data-urls="encodedurlformaps" data-height="800px"></div>
```

And I try to build a map at init:

```
  $(function() {
var gps_data = [];

$(".my-leaflet-map").each(function(){
        var data = $(this).data();
        if (data['urls']) {
            data['urls'] = window.decodeURIComponent(data['urls']).split(',');
            data['map_id'] = $(this).attr("id");
            $(this).css("height", data['height']);
            gps_data.push(data);
        }
    });
 if (gps_data.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<gps_data.length; ++i){
            var ajax_calls = [];
            var boundsObjectForEachMap = new BoundsObject();
         var map = L.map(gps_data[i]['map_id']);
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                 attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
             for (var j=0; j<gps_data[i]['urls'].length; ++j){
                ajax_calls.push(
                    downloadFile(
                        gpx_data[i]['urls'][j], map, boundsObject)
                );
            }
        $.when.apply(this, ajax_calls).done(function(){
             map.fitBounds(boundsObject.boundsArray);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working with localhost maps... when I push it to internet it's not working.
I have bounds:

```
[[29.9264, -118.24368],
[34.14555, -90.07148],
[25.76168, -90.07153],
[30.79488, -80.19179],
[25.76168, -81.73198],
[36.85298, -75.97028],
[38.90716, -77.03691],
[40.7349, -74.0057],
[36.83468, -77.5785],
[38.90719, -75.97798],
[23.18892, -118.24368],
[34.12527, -102.55278],
[3.45165, -102.55971],
[23.64973, -76.53199],
[-50.09649, -81.22001],
[3.45165, -67.20001]]
```

First time opening it gives such fitBounds:
[image: first fitBounds]

Refreshing webbrowser (so probably geojson is in cache):
[image: second]

My guess is that it might be something wrong with ajax deferred, but I don't know what
Here is this in production:
http://velomelon.com/our-route/

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, more details from OP are available on [Leaflet issue #4739](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4739).

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but it seems to me that Leaflet behaves exactly the way your code requests it to do:

- The code sends a few AJAX requests, each returning different markers and polylines, at different places across Americas.
- At each AJAX success, the code performs a `fitBounds` on the received layers only (converted from GeoJSON response)

```js
var newLayer = L.geoJson(geojson);
map.fitBounds(newLayer.getBounds());
```

- Therefore, the map pans to different places across Americas, giving this impression of "random" `fitBounds` effect.
- Finally, your last AJAX request resolves, and your `jQuery.when` deferred on all requests executes, fitting the map to your entire layers.

```js
map.fitBounds(boundsObjectForEachMap.featureGroup.getBounds());
```

So for your intermediate steps, why not simply fitting bounds to your updated `boundsObjectForEachMap.featureGroup`, so that the map shows all that you already received, rather than just what it received last?
That way, it will gradually zoom out to show more content, instead of just the small pieces that belong to the last AJAX request data at "random" place.

Additionally, you will be able to get rid of your last `fitBounds` in `jQuery.when`, since the last AJAX success will complete your entire set of data / layers, and its `fitBounds` will therefore show your entire content already.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nyhh0g2w/22/

Comment: but for me in chrome/firefox this final ajax call is always called as last, but fitBounds called in this final function not always working (but not returning error) and I don't know what's going on. go there http://velomelon.com/our-route/ and for me it is only showing North America and both should be visible

Comment: Always works in the JSFiddle, so you probably have an issue in your blog implementation. For example, could be your strange height settings. Or how you store and retrieve your bounds, since you did not implement the above `fullGroup.getBounds()` solution anyway. You should at least make sure those bounds are correct.

Comment: I did as you adviced and still getting same effect, changed height. I made screencast of that: https://youtu.be/DeLw1SGSesY
after 40 seconds after each refresh Leaflet is showing another bounds, even as you see in console there are always 8 iterations of fitBounds (so all fitBounds were invoked).
I have same effect in jsfiddle, I'm clicking play and map is in another point of the bounds...

Comment: I still see nothing wrong: https://jsfiddle.net/nyhh0g2w/28/ Instead of just logging the number of `fitBounds` calls, try at least to check the bounds are correct. You can try logging the bounds as string using `.toBBoxString()`.

Comment: sorry to be such a pain...
great function toBBoxString! so new screencast with bbox string, which shows that fitBounds is correct but somehow in **jsfiddle** fitBounds show different place in the map. https://youtu.be/Qh4iguoXUFc
@ghybs - thank you very much that you're helping me!!

Comment: mmm looks like if you call several `fitBounds()` too quickly, the last ones may not have effect… could be a bug.

Comment: As a workaround, you could re-implement your last `fitBounds` once all AJAX request have succeeded, delayed by a few dozens of ms. For me 150ms looks to be fine.

Comment: Had the same issue, for me it seems that passing `animate: false` option to fitBounds fixes problem.

Comment: @tyger thank you for your input! It would be very helpful to provide a playground / JSFiddle / Plunker that reproduces your issue (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Otherwise it is as difficult to debug / help as it has been with OP's question.